# When i upload my code into the server, why my logout.php unable to work?

Tags: php, native, logout

here is my code in my logout.php.

```
session_start();
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    header("Location: ../index.php");
```

this code works properly when i run it in my localhost, but when i upload it into my server it didn't work, and makes me unable logout from my website.
please someone help me thru' this thank you.

Comment: have you directly call the logout.php page from your browser?

Comment: What happens when you execute logout.php? does it redirect to index.php or not?

Comment: "it didn't work" won't help us, let's debug it: instead of the header("location.. try to write var_dump($_SESSION); - what's the output when you run the file?

Comment: ive tried this code var_dump($_SESSION); but it didnt show anything, still in the same page with the white screen.

Comment: notice what version of php and webservice

Comment: when i execute the logout.php the url has changed into the route that i've write.. but it wont redirecting into index.php and i still can open the page in the member area. and this happen only in the uploaded site, but when i run it in my localhost it work properly.

Comment: use exit(); after header("Location: ../index.php");   exit();

Comment: In theory, you want an fully qualified absolute URL in a `Location` header, but in practice less will work. You should avoid "../" however -- if you can't form a full URL, can you at least make it "root-relative", i.e., start with a slash. You can use PHP to help form the URL if need be.

Comment: your logout page and index page are same directory or different directory ?

Comment: ive already tried to put exit(); in it, but also it wont work. and about my logout page i put it in different folder..
i also tried to put my url instead for my index.php use "../" but it didnt work as well..

Comment: . = current directory
.. = parent directory
So ../ only used when your index page is in parent directory of logout

Comment: yes, my index already in my parent directory of logout.

Comment: Have you tried an absolute path? http://www.yoursite.com/index.php

Comment: yes i've tried it, yet it doesnt work as well.. but now when i use direct link "./view/logout.php" on my site without using any route it and it works. here's my route code } elseif (strcmp($page, "keluar")==0) {
        header("location:./view/logout.php");
      } else {
        header("location:absen");

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple scenarios possible in which your logout.php won't work. The most common one is that somehow your permissions are incorrect and your session file cannot be created on the server.

To check if this is the case I advise you to enable error reporting. You can do this by putting the following lines at the top of your PHP file:

```
// Put this code in your logout.php temporarily
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

Following that, make sure that your session isn't already initiated.

```
// Replace session_start(); in all files with this
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
}
```

I hope the above code changes will show you what your error might be.

Comment: should i put 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
in every file?
and how about the
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
}
where should i put this code? i guess the problem is  the session file cannot be created on the server just like you said, but i don't know why.. i just dont get it why it wont work in my server cpanel but it work properly in my localhost..

Answer (score -2):

Make sure your session is initialized before destroying it.

```
session_start() ;
var_dump($_SESSION); // Check session is set/not
session_destroy() ;
header("Location: ../index.php");
```

If you have any session value print then surely we can destroy it.

Comment: it didnt shows anything, still in the same page with the white screen..

Comment: it should be comment not an answer